# Junit тестирование классов, написанных по MVC паттерну

Tags: java, junit

Есть код, состоящий из нескольких классов написанных по MVC паттерну. Как тестировать классы: каждый отдельно (Test Case) или все вместе (Test Suite). Почему?

Comment: Это так, меня интересует: можно применять и то, и то или только тест сьют

Comment: спасибо большое